# Размещение View внутри другого с учетом длины содержимого

Tags: android

Есть такой `Layout`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У `TextView1` вертикальный размер меняется в зависимости от количества текста в нем.

В `TextView2` содержится некий короткий тег.

Хочется сделать следующее. Если последняя строка текста в `TextView1` короткая (такая, что в оставшееся место помещается текст из `TextView2`), то оставлять его в углу. А если последняя строка длинная, так, что TextView2 закрывает ее окончание, то сносить его на строку ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я применяю такой аццкий хак

```
<string name="accident_row_content">%1$s \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0"</string>
```

Т.е. добиваю текст длинным "словом" из несхлопываемых пробелов, которые тупо добавляют еще одну пустую строку, если на них не хватает места.

Может для решения этой проблемы существуют более правильные пути?

Comment: ну подсчитать кол-во символов (длину строки) минус кол-во символов от тега. От это зависит как рисовать TextView. Но мне кажется очень странно делать такое смещение, по идеи должно быть всегда как во 2м варианте, ну как в мессенджерах во всех, у них просто сам статус вниз переходит и всё. Ну напилить такое быстро можно, просто убедится точно вы этого хотите? имхо странное решение

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei подсчет символов не годится от слова совсем, так как шрифт не моноспейсный

Comment: а причем тут это вам нужна разница, то есть по сути влезет у вас след строка или нет, это раз во вторых вы можете в Android достать размер в рантайме. Просто это сейчас звучит, что лень делать, это уже другое. Здесь правильного пути в теории нет, просто мы делали равномерное  распределение текста в сообщениях, там как раз абсолютно тоже самое. Всё работает отлично

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Вот вам два текста, которые заведомо не помещаются на одну строку (допустим ширина view небольшая): `iiiii iiii ii iiiiii` и `Щщщ ЩЩЩЩ щщщ ЩЩ`. Как вы предполагаете определять, какая из них поместится, например, на 2 строки, а какая только на 3?

Comment: У Paint есть методы для вычисления ширины текста [`Paint.measureText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)) и [`Paint.getTextBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)). Плюс несколько [похожих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0). Может что поможет.

Comment: @eugeneek `measureText` и `getTextBounds` тут мало подходят, к сожалению. За ссылку спасибо, не подумал искать про "обтекание". Но что-то там какие-то совсем адские решения. :)

Comment: а не смотрели в сторону FlexBoxlayout'a? https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @IvanVovk потому, что он совсем про другое